# How to parallelize processing from S3 to S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parallel-processing

I have a process that identifies an object on an S3 bucket that must be converted using our (fairly simplistic) custom Java code.  The output of this conversion is written to a different prefix on the S3 bucket.  So it's a simple, isolated job:

1. Read the input stream of the S3 object
2. Convert the object
3. Write the output as a new S3 object or objects

This process is probably only a few thousands lines of data on the S3 object, but hundreds (maybe thousands) of objects.  What is a good approach to running this process on several machines?  It appears that I could use Kinesis, EMR, SWF, or something I cook up myself.  Each approach has quite a learning curve.  Where should I start?

Comment: Could you provide more context about volume (GBs?TBs?PBs?), velocity (Online? Batch?) and variety (Same/multipe data types?)

Comment: This is a batch process that will dump data every 12 hours and we want to process it as fast as possible.  When things get rolling, this could be about 100GB/run.  It's the same type of data for every record.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it is a batch process and volume will grow (for 'only' 100GB it can be an overkill), Amazon Elastic Map Reduce (EMR) seems like a nice took for the job. Using EMR, you can process the data in your Hadoop Map Reduce jobs, Hive queries or Pig Scripts (and others), reading the data directly form S3. Also, you can use S3DistCP to transfer and compress data in parallel to and from the cluster, if necessary.

There is a free online introductory course to EMR and Hadoop at http://aws.amazon.com/training/course-descriptions/bigdata-fundamentals/

Also, you can take a free lab at https://run.qwiklabs.com/focuses/preview/1055?locale=en

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) to queue each job and then process them in parallel on different machines (it has a much easier learning curve than Amazon EMR / SWF).

Keep in mind though that with SQS you might receive the same message twice and thus process the same file twice if your code doesn't account for this (as opposed to SWF which guarantees that an activity is only performed once).

Also, if your processing code is not utilizing all the resources of the machine it's running on, you can download & process multiple files in parallel on the same machine as S3 will probably handle the load just fine (with multiple concurrent requests).